# How do I export Internet Explorer' s cookies from the command line?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

The question is pretty self-explanatory so how do I export Internet Explorer' s cookies from the command line ? I know about Import and Export property from inside IE but what If I want to do this from a command line ?

Comment: IMHO nope. You can delete cookies like RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2. There is no documentation how to export them. What do you need it for?

Comment: I am thinking to backup them in a script, automatically and remotely.

Comment: That`s a bit of a hack: you might try to send keystrokes to either Internet Explorer or http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_cookies_view.html or http://www.backsettings.com/internet-explorer-backup.html and have the programs export the cookies for you.